# Sum of powers of regularized incomplete beta function

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, beta-function

Let $k$ and $r$ be natural numbers, and $p$ is a rational number in $[0,1]$. Is it possible to compute exactly in closed form the following sum?

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}I_{p}(i,k)^r,
$$
where $I_x(a,b)$ is the [regularized incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function).

**[Update 6 Feb 2019]**

**Motivation for $r=1$**

Let $X$ be a random variable distributed according to the negative binomial distribution with parameters $(i-k; k, 1-p)$, where the probability mass function of the negative binomial distribution with parameters $(k; r, p)$ is $f(k;r,p) = \Pr(X=k) = {r+k-1 \choose k} p^k (1-p)^r$. It is known that
$$
\Pr(X \leq i) = 1- I_{1-p}(i+1,k).
$$

On the other hand, we know that the variable $X$ is the sum of $k$ independent geometrically distributed variables with parameter $p$.
Hence

$$
  \mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{i=k}^{\infty} i \Pr(X_{\mathcal{P}} = i) =
    \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \Pr(X_{\mathcal{P}} > i) = 
    \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (1-\Pr(X_{\mathcal{P}} \leq i)) = 
    \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} I_{1-p}(i+1,k) = \frac{k}{p}.
$$

Therefore for $r=1$ we have 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}I_{p}(i,k) = \frac{k}{1-p}.
$$

Comment: I doubt it even having a closed form for the simple case of $r=1$.

Comment: @Ali, interestingly, for $r=1$ it can be computed in closed form. See my update.

Comment: I have have faced the same  issue  for the sum of squares (r=2), i will be glade if  you have any  hints ?